# Oracle SQL - Average Time Between Dates By Subject

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working in Oracle SQL. I have a table with IDs and Dates, and I'm trying to find the average time between dates by subject. It would look something like this.

TABLE

```
SubjectID     Date  
    1        8/01/2013 12:00:00 AM  
    1        8/31/2013 12:00:00 AM
    1        9/10/2013 12:00:00 AM
    2        1/01/2010 12:00:00 AM  
    2        1/21/2010 12:00:00 AM
```

I need to write a query that goes through that table by SubjectID, records the time between dates, and outputs the average of averages, so to speak. In this example, it would be time between the first and second rows (30 days) + the time between the second and third rows (10 days) / 2 (to get the average for subject 1, which = 20), and then the time between rows 4 and 5 (20 days) / 1 (to get the average for subject 2), and the output should be the average between those (20 + 10) / 2 = 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The average is actually the difference between the min and max values, divided by one less than the count.

For your data:

```
select SubjectId,
       (case when count(*) > 1
             then (max(date) - min(date))/(count(*) - 1)
        end) as AvgDifference
from t
group by SubjectId;
```

To get the overall average, use a subquery:

```
select avg(AvgDifference)
from (select SubjectId,
             (case when count(*) > 1
                   then (max(date) - min(date))/(count(*) - 1)
              end) as AvgDifference
      from t
      group by SubjectId
     ) t
```

Comment: Ah, much better than my approach.

Answer (score 0):

First get the duration between the rows:

```
select subjectid, 
       date, 
       date - lag(date) over (partition by subjectid order by date) as diff
from the_table;
```

Then get the average difference per subjectid:

```
select subjectid, 
       avg(diff)
from (
    select subjectid, 
           date, 
           date - lag(date) over (partition by subjectid order by date) as diff
    from the_table
) t
group by subjectid
order by subjectid;
```